# AWS - Unable to deploy java project to aws beanstalk from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services

I am trying to deploy amazon java web app to beanstalk(AWS Elastic Beanstalk for Tomcat 7) from eclipse using aws toolkit.

But i am facing following error,

```
Unable to update environment with new application version: 
Environment named awseclipse is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready. 
(Service: AWSElasticBeanstalk; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: da4518bf-13e4-11e4-9c13-97be58285d3c)
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably have another deployment or change pending. As the error message mentions, you need to wait until your environment is ready to deploy a new version.

Comment: So you just waited ? what is the exact solution here?

Comment: Yes. We have to just wait.